# Retrieve sections from config.json in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, config.json

Let's say I have a `config.json` like this:

```
{
  "CustomSection": {
    "A": 1,
    "B": 2
  }
}
```

I know I can use an `IConfiguration` object to get specific settings, i.e., `configuration.Get("CustomSection:A")`, but can I grab the whole hierarchy (in any type - even a raw string would be fine)?  When I try `configuration.Get("CustomSection")`, I get a `null` result, so I think this isn't supported by default.

My use case is grabbing entire configuration dictionaries at once without having to grab each individual setting - some properties may not be known at compile time.

Comment: what type of online searching have you done.. here is an example from [Dylan/JsonConfig GitHub](https://github.com/Dynalon/JsonConfig)

Comment: @MethodMan That's an interesting library, but I'm looking for something that can work with the built-in `IConfiguration` framework in ASP.NET 5.  Basically I'm not so concerned with parsing the section I get out of the config so much as I want to know how to retrieve it in the first place.

Comment: Example: `services.Configure<TypeHandlingCustomSection>(Configuration.GetConfigurationSection("CustomSection"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: updating this answer for the 1.0 release of Core.

This is possible now if you use a strongly typed object, for example:

```
public class CustomSection 
{
   public int A {get;set;}
   public int B {get;set;}
}

//In Startup.cs
services.Configure<CustomSection>(Configuration.GetSection("CustomSection"));
//You can then inject an IOptions instance
public HomeController(IOptions<CustomSection> options) 
{
    var settings = options.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have solved a similar problem where I wanted to bind the entire IConfigurationRoot or IConfigurationSection to a Dictionary. Here is an extension class:

```
public class ConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(this IConfiguration config, bool stripSectionPath = true)
    {
        var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var section = stripSectionPath ? config as IConfigurationSection : null;
        ConvertToDictionary(config, data, section);
        return data;
    }

    static void ConvertToDictionary(IConfiguration config, Dictionary<string, string> data = null, IConfigurationSection top = null)
    {
        if (data == null) data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var children = config.GetChildren();
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            if (child.Value == null)
            {
                ConvertToDictionary(config.GetSection(child.Key), data);
                continue;
            }

            var key = top != null ? child.Path.Substring(top.Path.Length + 1) : child.Path;
            data[key] = child.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

And using the extension:

```
IConfigurationRoot config;
var data = config.ToDictionary();
var data = config.GetSection("CustomSection").ToDictionary();
```

There is an optional parameter (stripSectionPath) to either retain the full section key path or to strip the section path out, leaving a relative path.

```
var data = config.GetSection("CustomSection").ToDictionary(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

configuration.Get is for getting a value to get a section you need

```
IConfiguration mysection = configuration.GetConfigurationSection("SectionKey");
```

Comment: I saw this method, but it returns another `IConfiguration` object; is there a way to enumerate all key/value pairs from an `IConfiguration`?  I've seen the strongly typed example at https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Jun/03/Strongly-typed-AppSettings-Configuration-in-ASPNET-5 but I'm looking for something more dynamic.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to enumerate, you can get the sub key values using get but you have to know the keys unless you map the section to a type as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to load and bind multiple sub sections with unknown keys like this (the syntax has changed slightly since your post; I recommend keeping an eye on the github project and their unit tests to see how it is currently working):

```
var objectSections = Configuration.GetSection("CustomObjects").GetChildren();
var objects = objectSections.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x =>
{
    var obj = new CustomObject();
    ConfigurationBinder.Bind(x, obj);
    return obj ;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For a detailed explanation, see
 https://dotnetcodr.com/2017/01/20/introduction-to-asp-net-core-part-3-the-configuration-file/

Below is an example from the site:

Config file has this:

```
"Languages": {
  ".NET": [ "C#", "VB.NET", "F#" ],
  "JVM": ["Java", "Scala", "Clojure"]
}
```

Load this configuration as follows:

```
IConfigurationSection languagesSection = configRoot.GetSection("Languages");
IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> languagesSectionMembers = languagesSection.GetChildren();
Dictionary<string, List<string>> platformLanguages = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach (var platform in languagesSectionMembers)
{
    List<string> langs = (from p in platform.GetChildren() select p.Value).ToList();
    platformLanguages[platform.Key] = langs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ConfigurationBinder` and read everything as `Dictionary<string, string>`

Here are some test cases that you can use as example: https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Binder.Test/ConfigurationCollectionBindingTests.cs

Comment: `ConfigurationBinder` is broken and what worse it won't be fixed. It cannot handle correctly arrays for example, instead of assigment it concatenates arrays.